# elasticsearch - aggregating counts on array matches

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my structure:

document 1 has

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Darrell",
      "age": "10",
    },
    {
      "name": "Karen",
      "age": "20",
    },
    {
      "name": "Gary",
      "age": "30",
    }
  ]
}
```

Document 2 has

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Karen",
      "age": "25",
    },
    {
      "name": "Gary",
      "age": "30",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Now, how can I perform count aggregation on individual array elements that matched the query?**

1. If I query for name:Karen, I need the count as 2.
2. If I query for name:Karen && age:20, I need the count as 1.
3. If I query for name:Gary && age:30, I need the count as 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map your `people` object as [`nested` objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), otherwise [it won't work as you expect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/nested-objects.html).

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "people": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
              "name": {"type": "string"},
              "age": {"type": "integer"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Once your index and mapping type have been created and after you've re-indexed your data, you'll be able to run your query like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "people",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "people.name": "karen"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "people",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "people.age": "20"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "people": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "people"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
             "field": "people.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks val. It shows me an error- "bool query does not support [filter]"

Comment: Oh, I'm using ES 2. and you probably aren't. I've updated my answer with a pre-2.0 valid query.

Comment: for some reason the terms aggregation did not work. I switched to value_count and it worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: I had added the name key already but still "terms" was not giving the correct counts...still trying to debug that. (But value_count was readily correct).